# Pandas DataFrame to BigQuery - Missing column of data

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery

I am running some RFM analysis on my data in Python and have adapted Joal Correia's github code (below), which outputs the results to a CSV, to also add the results to a dataframe then publish this to a BigQuery table.

It works, but I am missing the first column of my data in BigQuery, the 'customer' id, which is the only string in my results. The column is in the .csv, and in the dataframe in python, just not in the BQ results, can anyone tell me where I am losing this?

Note: I have removed most of the RFM code to de-cluttered this post, the lines below show my additions.

**UPDATE: I ran print(results.keys()) and I do not see 'customers' in this list, is this related to it not being visible in the export?**

```
Index(['recency', 'frequency', 'monetary_value', 'R_Quartile', 'F_Quartile',
       'M_Quartile', 'RFMClass'],
      dtype='object')
```

https://github.com/joaolcorreia/RFM-analysis

```
import sys, getopt
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from google.cloud import bigquery

.....

       rfmSegmentation['RFMClass'] = rfmSegmentation.R_Quartile.map(str) + rfmSegmentation.F_Quartile.map(str) + rfmSegmentation.M_Quartile.map(str)

# Output the results as a CSV
   rfmSegmentation.to_csv(outputfile, sep=',')

# Once the CSV is generated we also drop the results into a DataFrame and output to BigQuery.

   results = pd.DataFrame(rfmSegmentation)
   print(results.head())
   destination_table = 'xxx.RFM'
   project_id = 'xxx'
   results.to_gbq(destination_table, project_id, chunksize=10000, verbose=True, reauth=False, if_exists='replace', private_key='xxx.json')


   print (" ")
   print (" DONE! Check %s" % (outputfile))
   print (" ")
```

Here are the results of my script in the CSV, with 'customer' present and below in BigQuery, where the column is not present:

[image: CSV]

[image: BigQuery]

Comment: @sgDysregulation which schema do you mean? If you mean BigQuery, 'customer' does not appear in the schema.

Comment: As per my understanding of `pandas`, I guess `rfmSegmentation` is already a *pandas Dataframe*, otherwise you would not be able to use the `to_csv()` method. In that case, why are you converting it again to *DataFrame* ( `results = pd.DataFrame(rfmSegmentation)` )? I don't think that should affect, but I do not think that is necessary either. Going back to the main issue, if the *customer* column is not shown in the list of keys, that is a good indicator or where the error may be. Which is the result of `print(results.head())`, does it show the *customer* column?

Comment: Moreover, can you also print the *keys* from `rfmSegmentation`, like `print(rfmSegmentation.keys())`? What is the result. It should include the *customer* key, as the CSV file of the output does contain that column.

Comment: Hi @dsesto thanks for your reply, I managed to work this out, the 'customer' column was being used as the index, which was not sent to BigQuery. I replaced the index with range values and then the customer field was exported in the data as I wanted. It sounds like your suggestions would result in the same realization!

Comment: Glad I could help and you were able to solve your issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some further reading up on DataFrames I was able to solve my issue, it turns out that my 'customer' column was the index in the DataFrame. I used `reset_index` to replace this with a value range and then the data in my 'customer' column was exported to BigQuery as I wanted.